# Compare and merge two different generic List

Tags: android, list, sorting, generics, arraylist

I have in my code `two generic list`, One containing some `plans` and other containing `promocode details`, the size of these lists `can be different`, the only common elements available in both list can be two, lets say `id` and `name`.

So my question is, how can i compare these two lists and only retain `plans` containing same `id` or `name` and also retain the `plans` which are not present in the `promo list`, without writing my own code? if not, what is the best compare and merge method.

**`I have tried converting it to Collection and used retainAll`**

> sample plan json:

```
 {"id":14,"name":"60 Day","description":"60 Day","validity":60,"is_active":true,"price":7}
```

> sample promoplan json:

```
 {"id":6,"name":"120 Day","description":"120 Day","original_price":12.0,"new_price":0.0"}
```

**EDIT** *ultimate goal* **`(ie matching id's of both list are retained with new price in the plan list and also the non matching id's with the existing price on plan list)`**

Any kind of help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the lists elements themselves are actually JSON arrays.  Then write a custom comparator where you compare either the `id` or `name`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen .. Can you please guide?

Comment: Can you show the code containing the lists, possibly including the definitions?

Comment: well, first thing pops when you mention Comparing is overriding `equals()` but this step have several rules, and it might get tricky as they are 2 different classes (2 different types) can you confirm this @TimBiegeleisen ?

Comment: @Yazan and Tim Biegeleisen Please see edit

Comment: well, my thoughts on this is using `contains()` and this leads to overriding `equals()` so you can use a nested for loop to check items and add the matched in a 3rd list. my note on this is overriding `equals()` have rules you should comply to, in order to get correct result.

Comment: i have already implemented using two four loops, But when having around 500+ data objects.. it is creating performance issues.. I have tried `GUAVA`library but not quite getting a proper kickstart @Yazan

Comment: and also i dont want to create a new list..